# Cannot get correct syntax for Matrix Method in MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra to work

Tags: c#, matrix

I've created a 2D array of complex numbers as follows:

```
Complex[,] array32D = new Complex[3, 2] { { D44, D45 }, { D54, D55 }, {D64,D65} };
```

Wish to create a 3x2 DenseMatrix using array32D, then tried to call OfArray method and pass array32D to it to create matrixD.

```
DenseMatrix = MatrixD;
MatrixD = OfArray(Complex[,] array32D);
```

This 2nd line (MatrixD = OfArray...) does not work and returns error name 'OfArray' does not exist in current context. Why?

used following using statement:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex;
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the `OfArray` is a method of DenseMatrix (not some custom function with the similar name) then you should call it as `DenseMatrix.OfArray(array32D)`

Comment: @Serg - Yes, that does help for now no OfArray error. Thank you. But I still get an error for Complex{,} array32D. The literature states the following as a Static Public Function: DenseMatrix OfArray(Complex[,] array).  I assumed that array here is the name of the array I used, i.e. array32D. But I get a 1. syntax error; value expected, 2. syntax error ',' expected and 3. Complex is a type which is not valid in the given context error. I cannot find any example to clarify how this function is to be used.

Comment: Solved 1 and 2. I should have had DenseMatrix.OfArray(Complex[3,2], array2D) which is not in harmony with the format presented in the literature but anyway, now to solve 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a static function `OfArray` you need to explicitly specific class - `DenseMatrix.OfArray`
2. As per [documentation](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex/DenseMatrix.htm#OfArray) `OfArray` needs only the one argument - the 2-dimensional array of numbers. So, you need `DenseMatrix.OfArray(array32D);`. You dot't need to specify the array declaration (`Complex[,]`) when calling the function. This declaration is already specified in the function signature.

So, the final solution should looks like this (I additionally omitted the explicit array dimensions as the compiler can infer it from initialiser).

```
var array32D = new Complex[,] { { D44, D45 }, { D54, D55 }, { D64, D65 } };
var MatrixD = DenseMatrix.OfArray(array32D);
```

Of course this solution assumes that you already have variables `DD44 ... DD65` declared with some compatible type (`Complex, double`, etc) and initialised.

Comment: Yes, I realised after reading @Serg's post again (carefully!) that (Complex {,} array) is the method signature - all I should have done is pass the array32D to it when calling the method. Rookie error but then I am very much still a rookie! Thanks, all good now.